# Is the polarization defined by the divisor is defined up to translation?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian variety, $D \subset A$ an effective divisor inducing the principal polarization on $A$.

Question: Does divider $D + p= \{q+p \mid q \in D \}$, for $p \in A$ induce the same polarization as divider $D$?

Comment: What does `same polarization' mean to you? If you are asking whether the two divisors are linearly equivalent, the answer is no.

Comment: "same polarization" for me means: $c_1([D])=c_1([D+p])$, that is, the line bundles given by the dividers have the first Chern class  equal. Equivalently, the line bundles $[D]$ and $[D+p]$ are analytically equivalent.

Comment: Ok, where does your chern class take values? If in $H^2(A,\mathbb{Z})$, the answer is yes, but if in the Chow group, the answer is no. Again, please explain what you mean by `analytically equivalent'.

Comment: The first Chern class $c_1(L)$ of a holomorphic line bundle $L \in Pic(A)$ on $A$ is the image of $L$ under the boundary map $c_1:Pic(A)\longrightarrow H^2(A, \mathbb{Z})$. You can take as definition for "analytically equivalent" as $c_1(L_1)=c_1(L_2)$, for line bundles $L_1, L_2$ on $A$.

Comment: Under the chern class map for you, then $\mathrm{Pic}^0$ goes to zero. So, the divisor and any translate have the same chern class, since its difference is in the kernel of Chern class map.